# Output function for Aho-Corasick algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, substring, aho-corasick

I have a problem with implementation of output function for Aho-Corasick algorithm. In general I don't quite understand how output function works.
According to [this paper](http://cr.yp.to/bib/1975/aho.pdf) in goto function I put appropriate pattern index to output, like `output[currentState] = patternIndex;`
in fail function I merge existed output for state S with output for failed state S, like `output[s] += output[fail[s]];` in search function I use such condition: `if (output[state]) != 0) then we find our pattern.` 
But such approach doesn't work and I've got nonsenses result. Maybe, pseudocode for output function means something else in that paper, I don't know.

Output function with bitwise mapping which I've got [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/aho-corasick-algorithm-pattern-searching/) also doesn't work correctly in most cases. Wrong patterns match with this condition `if ((output[currentState] & (1 << j)) != 0)`
Besides, I don't quite understand why bitwise operations are using for output calculation.

I will be grateful for any help in clarification of implementation of the output function.

EDIT1: seems, that problem was in overflowing after bit shift operation:  `output[currentState] |= (1 << i);`and `out[currentState] & (1 << j)`
So far, tried to use BigInteger, but seems, that it causes a problem with performance.

EDIT2: tried BitSet, but performance still very poor. Maybe, there is a problem in implementation of algorithm, i don't know.

Comment: The paper is mostly about *constructing* the state machine (by generating the tables) The output "function" is in fact also just a table: the list (possibly/mostly empty) of output-symbols that should be emitted when the state is reached.

Comment: I understand it, but I don't quite understand how to fill an output

Comment: I taught a class on data structures and put together [some slides on the Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs166/cs166.1166/lectures/02/Slides02.pdf), which shows how to come up with the algorithm from first principles. The description of how to compute output links starts on Slide 405.

Comment: `I don't quite understand why bitwise operations are using for output calculation.` Just to avoid 2-dimensional arrays. The bitmasks are used to encode a small set of small ints (the numbers of the matching strings)

Answer (score 0):

The 32 bits bitwise operation just like this below

pattern: `he, she, his, hers`

```
input: shethehishetheehershehehishe
```

The total state number is `9`, and `2, 5, 7, 9` state is final state like below
[AC automation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1n4O.png)

Output function represented which a pattern you matched in current state.
like :

```
out[2] = he, out[5] = she/he, out[7] = his, out[9] = hers

The code "out[currentState] |= (1 << i)" just like below 

out[2] = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 <-- means number 1(he) pattern matched 

out[5] = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0110 <-- means number 1(he) and number 2(she) matched
```

so use `output[currentState] & (1 << j)` to calculate which pattern is matched.

This operation just like one-hot encoding. And the operation problem is type of output function. If the output function type is `32` bits, and we can just search at most `31` patterns. Because over the `31` patterns, it will overflow by shifting.